# Lagrange's Theorem exercise

Tags: analysis, derivatives

Be $u : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a $C^2$ function. Proof that exists a $x \in \mathbb{R}$ with $0<x<2$ for which $u(2)-2u(1)+u(0)=u''(x)$

Applying Lagrange's Theorem I showed:

$u(2)-u(1)=u'(x_1)$ with $0<x_1<2$

$u'(x_1) - u'(0) = u''(x_2) x_1$ with $0<x_2<x_1$

$u(2)-u(1)-u'(0) = u''(x_2)x_1$

How i can finish?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f \in C^2(a,b)$ then for every $x\in (a,b)$ and suitable $h>0$
$$
f(x+h)=f(x)+hf^{\prime}(x) + \frac{h^2}{2}f^{\prime\prime}(\xi_+), \qquad \xi_+ \in (x,x+h)
$$
and 
$$
f(x-h)=f(x)-hf^{\prime}(x) + \frac{h^2}{2}f^{\prime\prime}(\xi_-), \qquad \xi_- \in (x-h,x).
$$

Summing we get 
$$
f(x+h)+f(x-h) - 2f(x) = h^2\frac{f^{\prime\prime}(\xi_+) + f^{\prime\prime}(\xi_-)}{2}
$$
and by intermediate value theorem for $f^{\prime\prime}$ there exists $\xi \in (x-h,x+h)$ such that 
$$
f(x+h)+f(x-h) - 2f(x) = h^2 f^{\prime\prime}(\xi)
$$

Now just plug into the last equation $f=u$, $(a,b)=(0,2)$, $x=1$ and $h=1$.

Comment: Thank you a lot, really kind. Tried to solve without Taylor but it seems the best way.

Comment: You are welcome.